# SQL Server sort by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of transactions in SQL Server 2016 with a column called `mthweekyr` where each row in this column has as a string, the month number, week number of the month, and year of the transaction, where week number is determined by day of the month / 7.

For example, if the transaction date was: `2018-09-28`, this would appear as `9-4-2018`.

The problem is that the original transaction date column is not actually in the table, and I would like to sort these transactions by the `mthweekyr` column, but am unable to do so because this column is not a date type, it is a string type. (I don't make the tables, I just use them!)

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: So if the real need here is to sort (and not convert to a date) then reformatting this string as `YYYY-MM-W#` would allow you to sort lexicographically and get your desired results. That's where I would focus my time.

Comment: @JNevill great suggestion, thanks. What would be the syntax in T-SQL for this?

Comment: Aside: You may want to add a _persisted computed column_ to the table with an appropriate data type, e.g. `date`, to hold the value. It can also be indexed. That should make living with the table a rather easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way...

```
declare @table table(mthweekyr varchar(10))
insert into @table
values
('9-4-2018'),
('8-4-2018'),
('9-5-2018'),
('7-5-2018'),
('7-4-2018'),
('9-5-2017'),
('9-4-2017')

select *
from @table
order by
    cast(right(mthweekyr,4) as int)                          --order by year first
    ,cast(left(mthweekyr,charindex('-',mthweekyr)-1) as int) --order by month. Works for single or double digit months
    ,left(right(mthweekyr,6),1)                              --order by week number which is always a single digit, since it's the week number of the month not the year.
```

Comment: This works too. In fact this is probably easier to understand (and less code) than my solution. Should produce nearly identical execution plans. +1 from me.

Comment: i realized i have to cast the month and year since multi-digit will mess up ordering. *should* work now though. Thanks @SeanLange

Comment: See my answer.  --- you can simply use the implicit conversion to date.  I suspect you were overthinking it

Answer (score 3):

**Late answer**, but perhaps a thinner alternative.

You can simply use the implicit conversion of m-d-y to date

**Example**

```
declare @table table(mthweekyr varchar(10))
insert into @table
values
('9-4-2018'),
('8-4-2018'),
('9-5-2018'),
('7-5-2018'),
('7-4-2018'),
('9-5-2017'),
('9-4-2017'),
('10-4-2017'),  -- added 2 digit month
('10-5-2017')   -- added 2 digit month

Select *
 From  @table
 Order By convert(date,mthweekyr)
```

**Returns**

```
mthweekyr
9-4-2017
9-5-2017
10-4-2017
10-5-2017
7-4-2018
7-5-2018
8-4-2018
9-4-2018
9-5-2018
```

Comment: Technically this will work too now that I think about it

Comment: Hmmm. Great catch! So what is that _implicit conversion_ anyway? The documentation say that the default format, that the `CONVERT` assume is `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`. Is the _implicit == default_ at all?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev There are many such implicit conversions.  For example:  Select try_convert(datetime, 'Aug 26, 2017 9:00am')
      ,try_convert(datetime, 'August 26, 2017 9:00am')
      ,try_convert(datetime, '20170827')
   ,try_convert(datetime, '08/27/17')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yeah, I got that. Still wondering how/why the engine figures out which number represents the month and which one the date... Anyway this is genius +1 from me.

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev The default SET DATEFORMAT is YMD but will accept MDY.   However if you SET DATEFORMAT DMY the implicit conversion will accept DMY  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890053/sql-table-datetime-column-format/45890288#45890288

Answer (score 2):

Using JNevill's suggestion you could leverage PARSENAME for this.

```
declare @Date varchar(20) = '9-4-2018'
select PARSENAME(replace(@Date, '-', '.'), 1) + '-' + right('00' + PARSENAME(replace(@Date, '-', '.'), 3), 2) + '-' + right('00' + PARSENAME(replace(@Date, '-', '.'), 2), 2)
```

This returns 2018-09-04

You could also do some string manipulation but that starts to get rather tedious.

Comment: Bless you for putting that together. I took a stab, but I haven't written tsql in forever and string parsing makes my heads spin.

Comment: Hi thanks. I see you've only declared the @date for one date. How would you do it if there was a column of them just out of curiosity?

Comment: @JNevill agreed. messing with strings is ugly. That is exactly I chose the shortcut of PARSENAME for this. :)

Comment: If this was a column you would just replace the variable with your column name in your order by.

Comment: beat me too it. Good use of `PARSENAME` for sure.

Comment: I suspect you were overthinking this one ... see my answer

Answer (score 1):

obviously not the most efficient I'm sure but to brute force it...

```
order by substring(@theStr, len(@theStr) - 4 + 1, 4)  
                + substring(@thestr,  charindex('-',@Thestr)+1,1)
                + right('00' + substring(@thestr, 1, charindex('-',@Thestr)-1),2)
```

here's how to get there by pieces:

```
declare @thestr varchar(255) = '9-4-2018'

Declare @SortStr as Varchar(255)

--year
Select @SortStr = substring(@theStr, len(@theStr) - 4 + 1, 4) 
print @Sortstr
--day
Select @SortStr = right('00' + substring(@thestr, 1, charindex('-',@Thestr)-1),2)
print @sortStr

--week
Select @SortStr = substring(@thestr,  charindex('-',@Thestr)+1,1)
print @sortStr

Select @SortStr = substring(@theStr, len(@theStr) - 4 + 1, 4)  
                + substring(@thestr,  charindex('-',@Thestr)+1,1)
                + right('00' + substring(@thestr, 1, charindex('-',@Thestr)-1),2)
```

will yield this output

```
2018
09
4
2018409
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know what the algorithm for date hashing is you can restore the original dates into a new column and then sort on it. Something like:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(datetime2(1), 
    RIGHT(@mthweekyr, 4) + '-' + 
    LEFT(@mthweekyr, CHARINDEX('-', @mthweekyr) - 1) + '-' + 
    SUBSTRING(@mthweekyr, CHARINDEX('-', @mthweekyr) + 1, 
        CHARINDEX('-', @mthweekyr, CHARINDEX('-', @mthweekyr) + 1)
            - CHARINDEX('-', @mthweekyr) - 1)) AS EstimatedDate
FROM theTable
ORDER BY EstimatedDate
```

## UPDATE

So the above is the long, harder way.

A smarter approach would be to leave the heavy lifting to the SQL Engine and use the third parameter of the [`CONVERT` function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx), which specifies the style of the input. As the `mthweekyr` basically represents a USA style of `mm-d-yyyy`, the query will look like:

```
    SELECT *, CONVERT(datetime2(1), mthweekyr, 110) AS EstimatedDate
    FROM theTable
    ORDER BY EstimateDate
```