# SQL Table datetime column format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried googling to get an answer but in vain. Below is my requirement

1. User has an option to insert data into a table which has export_date as datetime
2. When they execute insert statements, I want to ensure that they have keyed in date in "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" format. If not, don't allow insert queries to run.
3. Or allow the user to enter date in any format like dd-MM-yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy but internally convert it into the required format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" and store

Can someone help/guide me?

Comment: Actually, the only two formats that are guaranteed to work, regardless of collation setting are YYYYMMDD & YYYY-MM-DD... Beyond that, the only way to tell is the user used MM-DD-YYYY vs DD-MM-YYYY is if the day is greater than 12, otherwise there is no way to tell.

Comment: @JasonA.Long: language setting, not collation. And `YYYY-MM-DD` is *not* safe without a time, per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I stand corrected, Thank you for the info.

Comment: If you're processing data outside the database, enforce the format there, and pass a typed `DATETIME` parameter to the database. If you're only concerned with what people do inside the database, either leave it up to them to get it right, or don't grant them `INSERT` permission at all but demand they call a stored procedure, where you can do the checking. Even then, it is not possible for you to tell that `01-02-2000 00:00:00` is February 1st and not January 2nd from a user who thought the format was `MM-dd-yyyy`. That's why you shouldn't allow ambiguity in the first place.

Comment: thanks, John, and ikaikastine for your help. After reading through comments and answers, I have decided not to depend on users to format the date column. I came up with a small java utility that parses excel and uploads data to the table in the format that I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Set DateFormat**

**Example**

Used data type of `date` for illustration, but clearly you can use `datetime`

```
Set DateFormat DMY
Select try_convert(date,'15/08/2017')   -- Returns 2017-08-15

Set DateFormat MDY
Select try_convert(date,'15/08/2017')   -- Returns NULL

Set DateFormat YMD
Select try_convert(date,'15/08/2017')   -- Returns NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You will likely run into issues if you want the user to input the date in the "dd-MM-YYYY" format since if the user inputs in the mm-dd-yyyy format, you'll get different results. "YYYMMDD" is a generic format that SQL Server will always interpret properly.

Once you get the date from the user, you can convert it using the particular format that you want. The following will convert the date to the ISO8601 format:

```
SELECT   
    GETDATE() AS UnconvertedDateTime,   
    CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601  ;  
GO
```

For more information on the specific date formats, I'd recommend checking out [Microsoft's Convert Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#BKMK_examples).